# kill tcp process

Tags: vpnc

all:

How can I kill such a process?

```
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
    tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
    tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

I am trying to use my VPN account, but it gives such an output:

```
eddy@eddy-ThinkPad-Edge-E430:~$ sudo vpnc
Enter IPSec gateway address: 130.101.72.100
Enter IPSec ID for 130.101.72.100: Zipnet
Enter IPSec secret for Zipnet@130.101.72.100: 
Enter username for 130.101.72.100: yz74
Enter password for yz74@130.101.72.100: 
vpnc: Error binding to source port. Try '--local-port 0'
Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:500: Address already in use
```

Is this a problem of my computer or the server?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to run `netstat` with `sudo` to see all available PID's and program names, then you can use PID's to kill them. My example

```
xieerqi:$ sudo netstat  -tulpan                                                                       
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1155/master     
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2035/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      902/inetd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      871/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2453/cupsd
```

Second, those two programs, on port 53 and 631 are your local dnsmasq and printing services. You do not have to worry about them. If you want, you can disable these by editing `/etc/init/cups.conf` and `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` files.